# How can I change the direction text flows in a drawstring?

Tags: c#, printing, drawstring

I'm making a label printing thing for a candy shop in C#.  The label printer stock is narrow and tall, like a portrait style format so I'm printing using

```
System.Drawing.StringFormat drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical);
```

to do it so the outputted label will be landscape oriented.  Everything was going smoothly until I got to the point where ingredients would go.  I defined a rectangle to enclose the space where it would be and it prints, but the text flows in the wrong direction. The label is designed so the "top" would be the right long edge and text flows to the left.  Problem is, my drawstring text starts left and flows right.  Example here:

[image]

What do I do to make it flow the other way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out.  I changed it to `System.Drawing.StringFormat drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical | StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft);` and now it works perfectly :)